# Retornar consulta WebSQL como Array para uma variavel global

Tags: javascript, html5, websql

Estou utilizando um banco de dados WebSQL para salvar uma informação de licença de uso em um aplicativo PhoneGap. Em todo momento do sistema precisarei acessar essa informação, por isso tenho a intenção de salvar isso em uma variável global em forma de um array. Essa licença de uso, ao abrir o programa eu executo uma função para buscar as informações no WebSQL da mesma, mas não estou conseguindo inserir o retorno da função dentro dessa variável global. Aqui vai o código:

```js
<!-- language: lang-js -->


//license
LIC = [];

//WebSQL Connect
conn = openDatabase('test', 'test', 'test', 200 * 1024 * 1024);

//return license
function(){

    conn.transaction(function (tx) {

        //sql
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM license', [], function (tx, results) {

            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            //create array response

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){

                //insert values on response
                LIC['cpfCnpj']     = results.rows.item(i).cpfCnpj;
                LIC['serial']      = results.rows.item(i).serial;
                LIC['apiHash']     = results.rows.item(i).apiHash;
                LIC['status']      = results.rows.item(i).status;

            };

            console.log(LIC); //aqui LIC retorna

        }, null);

        console.log(LIC); //aqui não retorna

    });

}

console.log(LIC); //aqui não retorna
```

alguém tem uma luz ai pra me ajudar?

Comment: faz o seguinte, no `console.log(LIC);` colocar pra mostrar com um identificador pra diferenciar um do outro, tipo `console.log("1º - " + LIC);`, e coloca a ordem em que ele retornou os `console.log` e posta aqui, porque muito provável que o `console.log(LIC);` da Callback seja o último a ser executado por ser assíncrono, logo os outros que vão executar independentemente da resposta do Callback e não vão ter nada mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Pelo fato do método `executeSql` ser assíncrono, e ter de utilizar uma `Callback`, que só será executada quando tudo referente a mesma estiver "OK", o programa acaba executando as linhas de baixo, e por esse motivo há 2 `console.log(LIC);` que estão vazios, porque são executados antes da `Callback` ser executada, e somente oque está dentro da `Callback` é preenchido.
Oque pode ser feito basicamente é chamar outra função ao final da Callback para dar continuidade com oque deseja ser feito, sem ter mais complicações.

#### Dica:

Como no seu caso é uma consulta que pode ser consideravelmente grande, é de boa prática mostrar algo na tela enquanto faz a consulta, algum tipo de barra de progresso.

Comment: no meu caso, só preciso que ele faça tal consulta e que me retorne esse valor numa variável global. e que assim eu possa acessar a variável sempre que eu precisar

Comment: tudo bem, mas essa variável global só sera "alimentada" quando a `Callback` for executada

Comment: no seu caso, a `Callback` é a `function (tx, results)....` e sua variável LIC só será alimentada depois dessa function ser executada